# Converting .asc back to .gpg

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

I normally wouldn't ask but I can't find the answer on SO or google.

I'm using a library that accepts base64 encoded pgp public keys in string format. However, one of the components I need to convert has a key in .asc format. How can I convert it back to binary-pgp or base64-gp.

Sorry if it's really dumb question, I'm new to the pgp toolsets.

Thanks a lot!

Shane

Answer (score 16):

Turns out it's really simple:

```
gpg --dearmor file.asc
```

Source:
https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2011-October/026253.html

Comment: Note quite: it's either `gpg --dearmor file.asc` and the de-armored output will be in `file.asc.gpg` or `gpg --dearmor < file.asc > file.gpg` which reads and writes from/to stdin.

Comment: @ckujau careful with the last one: if gpg fail (or command doesn't exist), `file.gpg` will still be created, with a size of 0.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to avoid a final filename of `.asc.gpg`, you can use the `-o` option of `gpg`, like so:

```
gpg -o foobar.gpg --dearmor foobar.asc
```

(I don't recommend using `gpg --dearmor < file.asc > file.gpg` because if gpg fail or does not exist, file.gpg will still be created (empty file), which lead to unwanted side effect when working with automation).